# python3 how to set test passed in unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a test with a loop checking some condition.

I want this loop to break and test to be passed if condition is true, otherwise I want to mark test as failed after loop ended.

here is the code

```
while time.time() < timeout:
    if condition:
        self.assertTrue(True)
self.fail()
```

but this solution is not working, loop is not breaking with the assert, why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertions only break the test when they **fail**. In your original snippet, the assert inside the loop always passes, so the test continues uninterrupted. One approach to solve these types of problems is to keep a boolean outside the loop, and assert on it when the loop terminates:

```
test_passed = False
while not test_passed and time.time() < timeout:
    if condition:
        test_passed = True

self.assertTrue(test_passed)
```

Comment: That is what I am doing right now a solution, but there is also should be a break in a while loop after test_passed=True, so I though that can be more concise

Comment: @Semant1ka you could use a `break` statement, although I prefer adding the condition to the loop's condition (see in my answer above). Ultimately, it's a matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: > Assertions only break the test when they fail
Whoa, thank you, that is the case I haven't thought about really.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple asserts in a test, therefore an assert will not break a loop or return the function.

This should work for you:

```
while not condition and time.time() < timeout:
    time.sleep(0.1)

self.assertTrue(condition)
```